# Missing element: MPEG4-GENERIC audio RTP depayloader Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

When I try to record an RTSP stream with audio and video using gstreamer I get the above error. When only video is recorded it works but when audio pipeline is added the file size becomes zero and the above error is displayed. Further following is also displayed

Missing element: MPEG4-GENERIC audio RTP depayloader
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: No decoder available for type 'application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)MPEG4-GENERIC, streamtype=(string)5, profile-level-id=(string)1, mode=(string)aac-hbr, sizelength=(string)13, indexlength=(string)3, indexdeltalength=(string)3, config=(string)1188, a-tool=(string)"LIVE555\ Streaming\ Media\ v2016.01.29", a-type=(string)broadcast, x-qt-text-nam=(string)"KMStreaming\ Server", x-qt-text-inf=(string)ch01, clock-base=(uint)3130203504, seqnum-base=(uint)34845, npt-start=(guint64)0, play-speed=(double)1, play-scale=(double)1, ssrc=(uint)3216157947'.
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(921): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0

Answer (score 0):

There are two different MPEG4 audio RTP formats in the wild. `MP4A-LATM` and `MPEG4-GENERIC`. See `RFC 3016` and `RFC 3640` respectively.

Looks like GStreamer only supports `MP4A-LATM`. So basically, yes, the format you are trying to receive is not supported.

Comment: Thank you. This means I will have to change the audio stream of the rtsp streaming source

Comment: If possible this seems like the easiest way.

Comment: I've tried to use decodebin in the pipeline, it gives me above error. Is it possible to use rtpmp4gdepay? Thank you Florian Zwoch